# Do I have to free the malloc memory in std::queue?

Tags: c++, queue, malloc, free, fifo

I have a doubt.
Let's say I have a buffer allocated with malloc as the following:

```
uint16_t buffer_length = 200; // !size is dynamic!, never static
uint8_t* buffer = (uint8_t*) malloc(200*sizeof(uint8_t));
// buffer then is populated somehow from 0 to 199
```

Now I have a std::queue which I need to FIFO several allocated buffers as the following:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer_vector(buffer, buffer + buffer_length);
std::queue<std::vector<uint8_t>> fifo_queue;
fifo_queue.push(buffer_vector);
```

Considering that I've decided to move from uint8_t* to std::vector because I can store more buffer information (length) in a single element. Now I want to take out the items from the queue:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> taken_item = fifo_queue.front(); // reads the FIFO item
fifo_queue.pop(); // removes from FIFO
uint8_t* taken_item_buffer_ptr = taken_item.data(); // takes the buffer ptr
uint16_t taken_item_buffer_length = taken_item.capacity(); // takes the size
```

Now I can handle the returned buffer from the FIFO, the question is, do I have to free the returned pointer? For example as the following:

```
free(taken_item_buffer_ptr);
```

Is this a good approach to store inside a FIFO dynamically-generated buffers?
Thank you.

Comment: One of the points of `std::vector` is that it manages the memory for you.

Comment: There is no point to allocating `buffer` and then copying it into `buffer_vector` (you still need to deallocate `buffer`). Just do `std::vector<uint8_t> buffer_vector(200);`.

Comment: Ok, lets say that I am going to use directly the std::vector instead of using the uint8_t* buffer. When I place it inside the std::queue and then when I take it back, do I have to make anything to "deallocate" or clear the allocated space? I mean something like calling the clear() method.

Comment: No, you don't need to clear or deallocate anything. The standard containers release memory when they are destroyed.

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector<uint8_t> buffer_vector(buffer, buffer + buffer_length);`
This will copy the data in buffer into a new memory region, "managed" by `buffer_vector`.
Additionally `fifo_queue.push(buffer_vector);` will copy the data again. A second copy of the data is managed by `fifo_queue`.

So actually your question does not really make sense. You have to free `buffer` to avoid memory leaks. You don't have to free `buffer_vector` or `fifo_queue`.
You also don't have to free `taken_item_buffer_ptr`.
`taken_item` is a object of std::vector type and will call its destructor when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

> do I have to free the returned pointer?

You need to, and are allowed to `free` only what you have allocated with `malloc` (or related C standard functions). You did not use those functions to get `taken_item_buffer_ptr`, so you aren't allowed to `free`.

`std::vector` maintains its own buffer. When the vector object is destroyed, it will free the memory in its destructor.

You are required to free `buffer` since you allocated that with `malloc`. But you shouldn't have allocated it in the first place. You should create a vector in the first place, and populate that directly.

> Is this a good approach to store inside a FIFO dynamically-generated buffers? Thank you.

What I would change:

```
fifo_queue.emplace_back(buffer_length);
//  fifo_queue.back() then is populated somehow from 0 to 199

//...
std::vector<uint8_t> taken_item = std::move(fifo_queue.front());
fifo_queue.pop();
```

to avoid unnecessary copying the buffer.

> ```
> uint16_t taken_item_buffer_length = taken_item.capacity(); // takes the size
> ```

This is wrong. Capacity is not the size. You can get the size using the member function `size`.